# AJAX load file reference and iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

does many iframe affects the loading time of a website?and about the ajax, assuming that i have 2 jsp page.the first one have ajax that is calling the second jsp page. both of the pages have java script functions for example they have the same function called funcA(); and i call the second jsp page using ajax. which function will be executed?the function in first page or in the second page? and do i have to import the css in the second page?or it access the css in the first page?i am just confused in using ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iframes takes time to load, and the bandwidth of your client is always limited. So many iframes does affect loading time more or less.

Ajax it self do not make changes to the web page document. You are modifying the document by changing innerHTML or appending elements. The CSS style sheet and JavaScripts are shared in this case, and since the second page is loaded later, then funcA of second page would be called.

Comment: thanks for a clear explanation.

Comment: another question sorry, then when should/can i use iframe?

Comment: @KerPPag iFrame is always deprecated, use it when you're dealing with those legacy browsers where AJAX is impossible. iFrame is hard to control with JavaScript because there will be multiple DOM documents and different browsers have different ways to access them.

Comment: another question pops out of my mind. assuming that i have a ajax that send data to the servlet and the servlet responds with 
i.e (out.println("<input type="text"/>") would they still share the CSS and javascript?

Answer (score 1):

This article explains exactly how an iframe works regarding time:
[Iframe loading techniques and performance](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance)

The answer about calling jsp from another jsp depends on how you use these jsp, i.e. if you are using portlets. If you are using portlets you can load your css and js files when the portlet is loaded and so every jsp inside the portlet will use the same files.

If you are not using portlets, then there will be a conflict between the function A and function B. I do not know if you can predict which function will be called.

Finally and generally speaking from my point of view the best practice is to load different jsp and css per page. It is easier to maintain them.

Comment: based on what i have read for me portlet it is more complicated than servlet right?

Comment: Yes. In every portlet you can have one or more servlets. If you work with portlets then it is far more complicated than working just with servlets.